# Can I make IDEA show a hint to use a Kotlin extension function instead of a Java original?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, warnings, shadow, extension-function

Consider this example of a fictive old Java library, which I can't change but want to adapt for my Kotlin projects.

```
public final class SomeOldJavaClass {
    private SomeOldJavaClass() { }

    public static SomeOldJavaClass wayTooLongFactoryMethod() {
        return new SomeOldJavaClass();
    }

    public String stupidlyLongNameForGetter() { return "hello"; }
}
```

I know that I can define extension functions in Kotlin like this:

```
fun SomeOldJavaClass() = SomeOldJavaClass.wayTooLongFactoryMethod()

val SomeOldJavaClass.value: String
    get() = stupidlyLongNameForGetter()
```

Now, can I somehow make IDEA show a hint (or a warning), which advises **against** the usage of original library names and suggests my extensions instead?

*I've seen such warnings about standard JDK classes/methods, can't remember which.*

Comment: You can add your own inspections with a structural replace pattern, but other than that, no. You see warnings for the JDK classes that are mapped to Kotlin classes. This mapping is [in the compiler's code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f1fd84f539ca5f5b314d0f1ce83c89ad94d26319/core/compiler.common.jvm/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/builtins/jvm/JavaToKotlinClassMap.kt). You can't modify it unless you fork the compiler.